# Extracting Columns of a .csv file and finding their index

Tags: python, csv

I have a big csv, file, and i wanna get all the values in it, that are stored in specific columns i know the name of.

Somehow i don't get it how to do it, but i think i am close :(

```
import codecs
import csv
import json
import pprint
import re


FIELDS = ["name", "timeZone_label", "utcOffset", "homepage","governmentType_label", "isPartOf_label", "areaCode", "populationTotal", 
      "elevation", "maximumElevation", "minimumElevation", "populationDensity", "wgs84_pos#lat", "wgs84_pos#long", 
      "areaLand", "areaMetro", "areaUrban"]

index=[]

with open('/Users/stephan/Desktop/cities.csv', "r") as f:
    mycsv=csv.reader(f)
    results=[]
    headers=None
    for row in mycsv:
        for i, col in enumerate(row):
            if col in FIELDS:
                index.append(i)
        print row[i]    
print index
```

My list index, is correct i think and gives me the right values ( column indices)

What do i have to add to my code to make it work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import csv

with open('/Users/stephan/Desktop/cities.csv', "r") as f:
    mycsv = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in mycsv:
        for col in FIELDS:
            try:
                print(row[col])
            except KeyError:
                pass
```

Comment: I am sorry.. i am new to programming, can someone elaborate that construct to me, "try:"  and then Keyerror ?

Comment: row[col] - row is a dict, col is a key in dict. In case col not presented in FIELDS  row[col] raise KeyError. Statement except KeyError: pass avoid raise of this error.

Comment: always gave me an indentation error, at the KeyError part :(

Comment: Try four spaces for try/except statements.

Comment: I tried exactly as proposed http://pastebin.com/yf33UTF0... can somebody tell me what i do wrong :(

Comment: It seems you use tab for placing statements, better use four spaces. After line "for row in mycsv:" you use tab 2 times, it have to be only one. try have to be exactly above except.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to print out all the values in those columns in `FIELDS`, what you want to do is:

```
for row in mycsv:
    for i, col in enumerate(row):
        # If this is the header row entry for one of the columns we want, save its index value
        if col in FIELDS:
            index.append(i)
        # If this is one of the columns in FIELDS, print its value
        elif i in index:
            print col
```

Comment: Gives me an invalid syntax at the "elif" i use python 2.7 ?

Comment: Post your whole code and I'll tell you what's wrong